# Why do I need to input my selection twice?

Tags: java, input, selection

Can anyone help me understand why program requires me to input my selection twice before proceeding?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String quit = "quit";
    String input =  "input";
    String print = "print";


    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("please enter a command : \n      1) Quit \n      2) Input \n      3) Print \n");

    String initialSelection = scan.next();
    boolean stringInput = scan.hasNext();
    boolean intInput = scan.hasNextInt();
    boolean boolinput = scan.hasNextBoolean();

    if(initialSelection.equalsIgnoreCase(quit)) {
        System.out.println("The program has quit.");
        System.exit(0);
    }else if(initialSelection.equalsIgnoreCase(print)){
        [constructor]

        do {
            System.out.println("\nplease enter a command : \n      1) Quit \n      2) Input \n      3) Print \n");
            initialSelection = scan.nextLine();

                if (initialSelection.equalsIgnoreCase(print)) {
                        new BonusArrayList();
                } else if(initialSelection.equalsIgnoreCase(quit)) {
                            System.out.println("The program has quit.");
                            System.exit(0);
                }
        } while (initialSelection.equalsIgnoreCase(print));

    }else if(initialSelection.equalsIgnoreCase(input)){
        System.out.println("\n Please enter some kind of value (ex: 123, hello, True)");
    }
}
```

I believe it is coming from the nested do-while statement, but I cannot seem to fix that issue. Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you either need to have

```
String initialSelection = scan.next();
```

or

```
        boolean stringInput = scan.hasNext();
        boolean intInput = scan.hasNextInt();
        boolean boolinput = scan.hasNextBoolean();
```

If you have both you need to enter twice